# How to recognize string as array with echo

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I have a shortcode for woocommerce that shows all orders placed by a customer, it works. However, I came to a piece of code that gives me the following message:

> **Notice:** Array to string conversion in /home/vwzidcur/public_html/wp-content/themes/astra-child/woocommerce/woo-shortcodes.php on line 67. On line 67 of my file i have echo.

Googling and reading the official php manual I came to the conclusion that the problem can be solved with implode or by iterating $downloads array with foreach. I tried but couldn't. I am relatively new to this, any help would be appreciated.

```
$customer = wc_get_orders(['customer_id' => get_current_user_id(),]);

foreach ( $customer as $order ) {
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

$downloads = $order->get_downloadable_items();

  if ($downloads){ 
  wc_get_template(
    'button-downloads-dashboard.php',
     array(
     'downloads'  => $downloads,
     ));
     }

echo '<div class="container_orders_img"> '. $downloads .' </div>';
}}
```

Comment: Do a `print_r($downloads)` and update the question with what the variable contains, then I can try helping with the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this;

```
// FIRST ALWAYS CHECK IF ITS AN ARRAY
if(is_array($downloads)){
  // START THE LOOP
  foreach($downloads as $product){
    // HERE YOU CHOOSE WHAT TO PRINT OF ALL THE DIFFERENT VARIABLES IN THE ARRAY
    echo '<div class="container_orders_img"><a href="'. $product['download_url'] .'" target="_blank">'. $product['product_name'] .' </a></div>';
  } // END LOOP
} // END IF ARRAY
```

Comment: Inserted like this it works. However i need to keep `echo '<div class="container_orders_img"><a href="'. $product['download_url'] .'" target="_blank">'. $product['product_name'] .' </a></div>';`  out of the foreach loop because i am building some tabs in css, i need to echo somewhere else and not inside loop. Is there any way to move it ?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Wordpress or WooCommerce and don't have the full picture, but it shouldn't  be a problem. If the method `$order->get_downloadable_items()` need to be inside the loop to work, then you could do the loop in place and store the output in a new variable instead of echoing it out.

Comment: As I'm relatively new to php, could you kindly point me to a code example of how to store the output in a new variable and loop just like you said ?

Comment: Okay, nothing, I did it. Place the example by modifying the question.